# Creating file on filesystem with java.io.File

Tags: java, file, properties-file

I'm trying to create an empty .properties file on my filesystem using java.io.File.

My code is:

```
File newFile = new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath() + "folder\\" + newFileName.getText() + ".properties");

if (newFile.createNewFile()){
    //do sth...
}
```

It says that it's impossible to find the specified path.
Printing the Files's constructor's argument it shows correctly the absolute path.

What's wrong?

Comment: 1- You can just use `new File("folder", newFileName.getText() + ".properties")` and it will store the file in the `folder` directory relative to your current location; 2. Make sure the path exists, as it will not be created for you by `createNewFile` (you can use `newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()`)

Comment: Many thanks, it works! In any case I would adopt your cleaner solution -but- why shouldn't works mine?

Comment: I don't really know, so much context is missing, but to start with `new File(".").getAbsolutePath() + "folder\\"` doesn't have a separator between the "." and "folder", so you end up with ".folder" instead (filling in for the absolute path instead of ".", but you get the idea)

Comment: Did you check write permissions for the target directory?

Comment: That was... I couldn't expected something so trivial. Thanks twice MadProgrammer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `new File("folder", newFileName.getText() + ".properties")` which will create a file reference to the specified file in the `folder` directory relative to the current working directory
2. You should make sure that the directory exists before calling `createNewFile`, as it won't do this for you

For example...

```
File newFile = new File("folder", newFileName.getText() + ".properties");
File parentFile = newFile.getParentFile();
if (parentFile.exists() || parentFile.mkdirs()) {
    if (!newFile.exists()) {
        if (newFile.createNewFile()){
            //do sth...
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Could not create " + newFile + ", you may not have write permissions or the file is opened by another process");
        }
    }
} else {
    throw new IOException("Could not create directory " + parentFile + ", you may not have write permissions");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the "." operator might be causing the error not sure what you are trying to do there, may have misunderstood your intentions but try this instead:

```
File newFile = new File(new File("folder\\").getAbsolutePath() + ".properties");
```

Comment: No, it doesn't, you can use `new File(".")` to create a file reference for the current working directory, just like `new File("folder");` will create a `File` reference to the file/directory called `folder` in the current working directory

Answer (score 0):

Trivially I missed that `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()` returns the project's absolute path with the `.` at the end so my `folder` whould be called as `.folder`. Next time I'll check twice.